# open drawer from epson tm t80 in c#

Tags: c#, pos

I have a epson ticket machine that prints well using this code -->

```
    static SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM10", 38400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            Byte[] cashDrawerCmd = { 27, 112, 0, 25, 250 }; 

            try
            {
                if (!(_serialPort.IsOpen))
                 _serialPort.Open();

                _serialPort.WriteLine(" ");
                _serialPort.WriteLine("*********Prueba*********** ");
                _serialPort.WriteLine("*********************** ");
                /* _serialPort.WriteLine(" " + GetLogo()); */
                _serialPort.WriteLine("Prueba \r\n");           

                _serialPort.Write(cashDrawerCmd, 0, cashDrawerCmd.Length);
              //is not working thiscode for open drawer

                 OpenDrawer(); //is not working this function neither   
                 Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
            }
} 
     public static void OpenDrawer()
        {

     _serialPort.Write(char.ConvertFromUtf32(27) +
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(112) +
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(0) +
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(5) +
    char.ConvertFromUtf32(250));

        }
```

I want to open de drawer machine but is not doing it. I have already looked up for info and in majority of docs says that the default commands are --> 27, 112, 0, 25, 250 , but it is not working in my console app.If you look the code above I have tried 2 ways and is not working both of them. I hope some can help me here. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried other timings / do you have documentation for the pulse timings for your drawer?